# Postgres - query JSON column value of nested object

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I'm using following schema for the JSONB column of my table (named **fields**). There are several of these **field** entries.

```
{
   "FIELD_NAME": {
      "value" : "FIELD_VALUE",
      "meta": {
         "indexable": true
      }
   }
}
```

I need to find all the *fields* that contain this object

```
 "meta": {
    "indexable": true
 }
```

Here is a naive attempt at having `json_object_keys` in where clause, which doesn't work, but illustrates what I'm trying to do.

```
with entry(fields) as (values('{
  "login": {
    "value": "fred",
    "meta": {
      "indexable": true
    }
  },
  "password_hash": {
    "value": "88a3d1c7463d428f0c44fb22e2d9dc06732d1a4517abb57e2b8f734ce4ef2010",
    "meta": {
      "indexable": false
    }
  }
}'::jsonb))
select * from entry where fields->jsonb_object_keys(fields) @> '{"meta": {"indexable": "true"}}'::jsonb;
```

How can I query on the value of nested object? Can I somehow join the result of `json_object_keys` with the table iself?

Comment: meta seems to occur in different levels. is this right?

Comment: @S-Man nope, that was an error. Thanks for pointing it out. Fixed.

Comment: Do you want the whole object "{login: {...}}" or only the key "login"

Comment: @S-Man I need the whole object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3d5d6316df4095e2afcf1e6e481181a0)

**First way**: using `jsonb_each()`

```
SELECT
    jsonb_build_object(elem.key, elem.value)        -- 3
FROM
    entry,
    jsonb_each(fields) as elem                      -- 1
WHERE
    elem.value @> '{"meta": {"indexable": true}}'   -- 2
```

1. Expand all subobjects into one row per "field". This creates 2 columns: the `key` and the `value` (in your case `login` and `{"meta": {"indexable": true}, "value": "fred"}`)
2. Filter the records by checking the value column for containing the `meta` object using the `@>` as you already mentioned
3. Recreate the JSON object (combining the `key`/`value` columns)

---

**Second way**: Using `jsonb_object_keys()`

```
SELECT
    jsonb_build_object(keys, fields -> keys)            -- 3
FROM
    entry,
    jsonb_object_keys(fields) as keys                   -- 1
WHERE 
    fields -> keys @> '{"meta": {"indexable": true}}'   -- 2
```

1. Finding all keys as you did
2. and 3. are very similar to the first way